# How to return values from forEach

Tags: java

In this method i dont need to print this values. I need to return them

```
public void showStoreProductQuantity(){

        productListQuantity.entrySet().stream().forEach((Map.Entry<Product, Integer> entry) -> {
        Product product = (Product) entry.getKey();
        System.out.print(product);
        Integer quantity = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(" Quantity is:"+quantity);
        });

}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You can use an integer array to return this values

Comment: Why don't you just do `return productListQuantity.values();`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you exactly need, but if you have to collect map's values to a `List`, then you'll have to `.map()` those and the `.collect()` them with the appropriate `Collector`:

```
return productListQuantity.entrySet().stream()
                          .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, you should change the methods signature to:

```
public List<MapValueType> showStoreProductQuantity() { }
```

where `MapValueType` is the type of the values in your `productListQuantity` `Map`.

Comment: I need to return them like combination: product+quantity, to get such kind of list:

Number:7 Price:91 Description-3 Name-4 Quantity:70

Number:1 Price:23 Description-5 Name-6 Quantity:10

Comment: Then you have to play a bit with the way you map the `Entry` elements.